# how to use context.getContentResolver() to execute a update with CASE WHEN statement

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

Having a sql statement with CASE to do the update field based on row id, without need to passing values.

```
"UPDATE accounts SET field= CASE WHEN id=(select id from accounts where id=0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END";
```

How to use context.getContentResolver() to execute it? Or any other way?

Comment: Is this your own `ContentProvider`? If it is anyone else's, you have no way of knowing what SQL syntax it supports, if any.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Thanks! Then maybe my question should be in android how to execute this type raw sql which does not require params?

Comment: Um, again, is this your own `ContentProvider`? Or are you querying somebody else's `ContentProvider`?

Comment: it is mine provider which extends the ContentProvider, which @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)

Comment: @lannyf in this case the best way is to implement rawquery

Comment: @lannyf you can add some path to your URI and check that path is there to handle the selection part properly

Comment: thanks Viktor! is it that in the override to use the selection as the raw sql statement, like: the selection would the raw sql string

@Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        mainThreadCheck();
        final int match = sUriMatcher.match(uri);
        
        if (match == _RAW_QUERY) {
           db.rawQuery(selection, null) 
        } else {
           // for non rawQury
        }
    }        is there anywhere some sample for implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go with ContentProvider and Path approach I'll suggest you to use some helper class:

```
public static class UriBuilder{
        public static final String FRAGMENT_RAW_UPDATE = "rawUpdate"; // here could be noNotify, conflict resolver pathes, etc.

        private Uri.Builder uri;

        public UriBuilder(Uri uri){
            this.uri = uri.buildUpon();
        }

        public UriBuilder(String uri){
            this.uri = Uri.parse(uri).buildUpon();
        }

        public UriBuilder append(String path){
            uri.appendPath(path);
            return this;
        }

        public UriBuilder append(long id){//points directly to item
            uri.appendPath(String.valueOf(id));
            return this;
        }

        public UriBuilder rawUpdate(){
            uri.fragment(FRAGMENT_RAW_UPDATE);
            return this;
        }

        public Uri build(){
            return uri.build();
        }

        public static boolean isRawUpdate(Uri uri) {
            return FRAGMENT_RAW_UPDATE.equals(uri.getFragment());
        }
}
```

In your content provider you better to have some helper methods to create URI with your brand new UriBuilder, something like:

```
public static Uri contentUri(String path, long id){
        return new UriBuilder(BASE_URI)
                          .append(path)
                          .append(id)//optional
                          .build();
}

public static Uri contentUriRawUpdate(String path){
        return new UriBuilder(BASE_URI)
                          .append(path)
                          .rawUpdate()
                          .build();
}
```

After you have all this in your code life would me much easier. To create raw update URI:

```
contentResolver.update(YourContentProvider.contentUriRawUpdate(DbContract.Table.CONTENT_URI), null, rawSql, null);
```

and finally in your ContentProvider's update:

```
    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

        if(UriBuilder.isRawUpdate(uri)){
            dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(...);
            return;// early exit
        }
        ... // standard logic for matchers here
        ... // dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().update(...); 
        ... // notify observers here
}
```

**UPDATE**:
I suggest that you understand risks and your ContentProvider would not be Public. Using this approach you can execute any SQL and in terms of security that is backdoor :)

Answer (score 1):

If your `ContentProvider` is backed by a SQLite database, the `ContentProvider` itself can do the `UPDATE` statement that you want, using `execSQL()`.

To specify that you want this specific `UPDATE` to be done, you can:

- Use `call()` on `ContentResolver`, which triggers `call()` on your `ContentProvider`. This basically lets you invent your own protocol, for requests that do not fit the normal pattern.
- Or, you can use a dedicated path on your `Uri`, along with `update()`. For example, if normally you are using `content://your.authority/stuff` to access the provider, use `content://your.authority/stuff/special_update` with `update()` to signal to the `ContentProvider` that you want this special `UPDATE` to be done.